# How do you sort a list with a while loop in Python?

Tags: python, computer-science

How do you sort a list with a while loop? Having a bit of a problem, thanks very much in advance.

```
a = [12,0,39,50,1]

first = a[0]

i = 0
j = 1
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] < first:
        tmp = a[i]
        a[i] = a[j]
        a[j] = tmp
    i += 1

print(a)
```

Comment: One of the simplest sorting algorithms is insertion sort; look up a sample implementation or explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty list that would store your sorted numbers

```
a     = [12,0,39,50,1]
kk    = len(a)
new_a = []
i     = 0

while i < kk:
    xx = min(a)      ## This would retreive the minimum value from the list (a)
    new_a.append(xx) ## You store this minimum number in your new list (new_a)
    a.remove(xx)     ## Now you have to delete that minimum number from the list a
    i += 1           ## This starts the whole process again.
print(new_a)
```

Please, note that I used the original length of the list a (kk) for the while statement so as not to stop the iteration because the length of the list a decreases as we delete the minimum numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the implementation of basic sorting using two while loops.
In every iteration, the minimum element (considering ascending order) from the unsorted subarray is picked and moved to the sorted subarray.
:

```
a=[12,0,39,50,1]
i=0
while i<len(a):
    key=i
    j=i+1
    while j<len(a):
        if a[key]>a[j]:
            key=j
        j+=1
    a[i],a[key]=a[key],a[i]
    i+=1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 # By using For loop
 def ascending_array(arr):
     print(f"Original array is {arr}")
     arr_length = len(arr)
     if arr_length <= 1:
        return arr
     for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
           if arr[i] >= arr[j]:
              arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    print(f"The result array is {arr}") # [0,0,0,1,10,20,59,63,88]
 arr = [1,10,20,0,59,63,0,88,0]
 ascending_array(arr)



 # By using While loop
 def ascending_array(arr):
     print(f"Original array is {arr}")
     arr_length = len(arr)
     if arr_length <= 1:
       return arr
     i = 0
     length_arr = len(arr)
     while (i<length_arr):
        j = i+1
        while (j<length_arr):
           if arr[i] > arr[j]:
               arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
           j+=1
        i+=1
     print(f"The result array is {arr}") # [0,0,0,1,10,20,59,63,88]
 arr = [1,10,20,0,59,63,0,88,0]
 ascending_array(arr)
```

For-loop is best in terms of performance. while-loop is checking condition every iteration.

Answer (score -1):

You can also concatenate two lists and sort them in decreasing/increasing order using this example:

```
x = [2,9,4,6]
y = [7,8,3,5]
z = []
maxi = x[0]
pos = 0
print('x: '+str(x))
print('y: '+str(y))

for i in range(len(y)):
  x.append(y[i])

for j in range(len(x)-1):
    maxi = x[0]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if maxi < x[i]:
            maxi = x[i]
            pos = i
    z.append(maxi)
    del x[pos]
z.append(x[0])
print('z: '+str(z))
```

Comment: This is not what the author is asking for.